# Configure package manager to use an NTLM Proxy

Tags: package, proxy

I've seen a few examples of how to setup Emacs to use Basic Auth proxies - is there a way to configure it to use an NTLM proxy?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone needs to answer this question, here's how I solved it:

Install CNTLM and configure it with your NTLM creds.

Set environment variables HTTP_PROXY & HTTPS_PROXY to the localhost presented by CNTLM

that should sort it